# Is it possible to convert live CD to alternate CD using Jigdo?

Tags: 12.04, live-cd, iso, cd-image, jigdo

Can I use **Jigdo** to convert a Ubuntu live CD to an alternate CD with minimal download? The CD image I have is `ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`.

Is it possible? Or should I have to download the alternate ISO?

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't convert live CD to alternate CD using Jigdo.
Jigdo does work similar kind of torrent. You can download and share files using it. I would recommend to not change or edit any official iso by any way. Rather prefer to download alternate iso.

Comment: Thanks for editing... but this still doesn't seem to answer the question. The question doesn't seem to be asking how to customize a live CD. If you believe jigdo *cannot* be used to convert a live CD to an alternate CD (I believe it cannot, as well), I recommend expanding this to state that and, if possible, explain why.